# Site Collection Unavailable to SharePoint Administrator

Tags: site-collection, farm-admin

I have a site collection that I am unable to locate in the SharePoint Admin Center. This site collection was created by someone clicking the "Create Site +" button on the home page. I am the Site Collection Administrator of the site collection, but am unable to "give" this site collection to the Admin account to make higher level changes that I need to make. Is there a way through the UI or Powershell that I can make SharePoint Admin level changes to this site collection?

Thanks!

Comment: it could be a group site. they don't show up under sites (yet)

Answer (score 1):

This was created as a Modern Team. These sites do not show up in the SharePoint Admin Center. Instead, you need to use the Preview admin center or PowerShell. You can enable Targeted Release for your SharePoint Admin accounts (or tenant-wide) and you should see a link at the top right of the SharePoint Admin center that links you to the preview.

[Introducing the new SharePoint Admin Center](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Introducing-the-new-SharePoint-Admin-Center/ba-p/109761)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. But what i did was simple. In modern page you will have created site+ and create post if am not wrong.

You just need to open the same site something like this.

https://ABCD.sharepoint.com/sitepages/home.aspx.

The one which you see will be under this url where you won't find admin site navigation /_layouts/15/SharePoint.aspx